# Appcache simply not caching files

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I'm testing a data collection idea for places with spotty mobile connectivity.

I'm working on the technology [test here](http://www.jessefagan.com/backbonetest/backbonedual.html)

I have the call to the manifest file in the HTML tag: `<html manifest="/manifest.appcache">`

Here is the manifest file

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2013-06-26

CACHE:
backbonedual.js
backbonedual.html

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
```

Finally, I have an `.htaccess` file in the same folder:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

And I've tested that, since when I load the [manifest file directly](http://www.jessefagan.com/backbonetest/manifest.appcache), the network section in the Chrome developer tools is telling me the correct MIME type.

But still, it doesn't work. And no resources are showing up as listed in: `chrome://appcache-internals/`.

Comment: I tested this on Firefox and it worked. It still doesn't work on Chrome. Is there something weird with Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to start with a working example. A very simple hello world. I created a cache manifest for it and it worked just fine.

Then I decided to slowly add elements from my other page to see which part breaks it.

And I only got to the first line.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

When I removed this line the application cache was working! Does anyone know why?

Comment: Where did you put the meta tag? When I use the same meta tag it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: If you update your question with the upper part of your html code, including the lines with manifest attribute and meta tag, it might be easier to test it.

Comment: I saw the link to your project and found it there.

Comment: The meta tag was outside the html tag. I think that was the issue. Firefox didn't have a problem with it, but Chrome did.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your application and I think the problem is in the manifest file. When you specify the files to cache you don't write the whole path. The files are located in the folder `backbonetest` and that need to be specified as well.

Rewriting your manifest file in the following way should work

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2013-06-26

CACHE:
backbonetest/backbonedual.js
backbonetest/backbonedual.html

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
```

Comment: That was a good idea. But it's still not working as expected. =/

Comment: I just realised you also have to change the path to the manifest...assuming the manifest file is in the `backbonetest` folder as well. The `HTML` tag should then be `<html manifest="/backbonetest/manifest.appcache">`

Comment: Or you could write `<html manifest="manifest.appcache">` and just skip the path completely...